# JavaScript: different results of regexp test inside and outside loop

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm iterating over links and chose what I need by regex.

```
var str = "http://([^.]*).time.com/($|(page/\d/))";
var reg = new RegExp(str); var arr = [], l = document.links;
for(var i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
console.log(l[i].href + '\t\t\t-' + reg.test(l[i].href)); 
}

>...
>http://newsfeed.time.com/page/3/           -false
>...
```

But:

```
/http:\/\/([^.]*).time.com\/($|(page\/\d\/))/.test('http://newsfeed.time.com/page/3/')
>true
```

What am I doing wrong? :) Thank you.

Comment: Why would you use a regexp constructor with a constant string? Just use a regexp literal like you used in the console.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you also need to escape the `.` characters in the regex. Again, it's two backslashes in string literals, one in regex literals. (Except that the first `.` doesn't need escaping because it's in a character class so the rules are different.) NB: Little things like this can sometimes compromise security. For example, if your code assumes that any URL matching this regex is trustworthy, a malicious person could circumvent it by registering the URL `http://my-malicious-url-time.com/`, which matches the regex as you've written it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash in the string version of the regex (i.e. use `\\d`):

```
var str = "http://([^.]*).time.com/($|(page/\\d/))";
```

So:

```
var str = "http://([^.]*).time.com/($|(page/\\d/))";
var reg = new RegExp(str); var arr = [], l = ['http://newsfeed.time.com/page/3/'];
for(var i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
    console.log(l[i] + '\t\t\t-' + reg.test(l[i])); 
}
```

gives:

```
http://newsfeed.time.com/page/3/            -true
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the backslash in `\d` when you specify the regex in a string. This is not needed in a regex literal, that's why it works. So this line:

```
var str = "http://([^.]*).time.com/($|(page/\d/))";
```

should look like this:

```
var str = "http://([^.]*).time.com/($|(page/\\d/))";
```